# moving images relatively

Tags: android

i have an image that rotates around an arbitrary point. but i need 3 such images to rotate simultaneously
this is how i try to implement the same

```
private void rotateLogo(float degrees){
    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
    //int radius = turntable.getWidth()/2;
    double radians = degrees* (Math.PI/180);
    double xcoordinate = 220 * Math.cos(radians)- 60;
    double ycoordinate = 220 * Math.sin(radians) + 50;
    matrix1.postRotate((int)radians, 220, 220);

    // people image
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams linLay  = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) peopleLogo.getLayoutParams();
    linLay.bottomMargin = (int)ycoordinate + 10;
    linLay.rightMargin = (int)xcoordinate + 10;
    peopleLogo.setImageMatrix(matrix1);
    peopleLogo.setLayoutParams(linLay); 
    rotateLogo2(degrees - 2);
    }

private void rotateLogo2(float degrees){
    double radians = degrees* (Math.PI/180);
    double xcoordinate = 220 * Math.cos(radians)- 60;
    double ycoordinate = 220 * Math.sin(radians) + 50;

    // people image
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams linLay  = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) serverLogo.getLayoutParams();
    linLay.bottomMargin = (int)ycoordinate + 10;
    linLay.rightMargin = (int)xcoordinate + 10;
    serverLogo.setLayoutParams(linLay);
}
```

in the above code i reduced the angle and rotate the second image using the same code, but the image doesnt rotate, it just disappears on touch.

i also tried to take the layout params of the first image before rotation and apply the same to the second image, but this doesnt work too..

the image disappears on rotation though at times it appears and then disappears

can anyone help me as to where i could be wrong or suggest any other approaches for the same?

Comment: And why you want to do this.. can u be little more clear about ur requirement ..

Comment: i have a UI that i have to implement which has certain animations i have to emulate

Comment: you can use canvas for that. can u please add a snap shot of current behavior and required behavior too. I can give u a brief answer with explanation !!

Comment: i had tried with canvas too.. but couldnt get through.. image upload sites are blocked here so cant add the snapshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refactor the code

```
private void rotateLogo(View logo, float degrees){
   Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();
    //int radius = turntable.getWidth()/2;
    double radians = degrees* (Math.PI/180);
    double xcoordinate = 220 * Math.cos(radians)- 60;
    double ycoordinate = 220 * Math.sin(radians) + 50;
    matrix1.postRotate((int)radians, 220, 220);

    // people image
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams linLay  = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) logo.getLayoutParams();
    linLay.bottomMargin = (int)ycoordinate + 10;
    linLay.rightMargin = (int)xcoordinate + 10;
    if (logo isInstanceOf ImageView) { 
        logo.setImageMatrix(matrix1);
    }
    logo.setLayoutParams(linLay); 
}
```

and call the method twice with different parameters..

```
rotateLogo(peopleLogo, degrees);
rotateLogo(serverLogo, degrees-2);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but this doesnt seem to work.. i feel im missing something related to setting layout params.

Comment: the rotation was not proper because of the layout parameters set in the main.xml.